# File upload from MVC controller to Web API using RestSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload

One of the features of my web application is the ability of the users to upload markdown files. I'd like to pass the file from a `MVC` controller to a `Web API` controller, afterwards the `Web API` will save the markdown file on a specific project folder. I'd like to know if it's possible. If yes, how to do it.

So for what I had in mind is having the `MVC` controller take a `HttpPostedFileBase` parameter and afterwards use RestSharp's `request.AddFile()` to send the file to the `Web API` controller.

MVC Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase upload)
{
    var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:4000/api/beneficiaries");
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    //todo send file to web API
    var response = client.Execute(request);
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, even if I haven't tested it:

```
request.AddFile(upload.FileName, upload.InputStream.CopyTo, upload.ContentType);
```

Depending of the api target method, and if you need some parameters sent with it, you might need:

```
request.AddFile(upload.FileName, upload.InputStream.CopyTo);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

request.AddParameter("filename", upload.FileName, ParameterType.RequestBody);
request.AddParameter("otherParameter", "Something here...", ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

Comment: I tried this and I'm getting an `InnerExceptionError` : Cannot close stream until all bytes are written, on `var response = client.Execute(request);`

Comment: In this case, maybe you need to copy the stream and are not able to reuse it. you could create a new Memory Stream before creating the `RestClient` instance by calling: `var targetStream = new MemoryStream()`. Then you copy the Upload FIle Stream to the Memory Stream: `upload.InputStream.CopyTo(targetStream)`. You might need to "rewind" the Target Stream back to the beginning: `targetStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)`. Now use the `targetStream.CopyTo` instead of `upload.InputStream.CopyTo` when executing `AddFile`. This could fix it.